# Media query not working with Motorola cell phone

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I've incorporated media queries that work great for iPhones.

I am running into issues with viewing my website from a Motorola cell phone. I am not sure what the cause might be. Or if I need to add something extra in my code to accommodate other cell phone devices other than iPhone. I have the same media queries set for 320px and 425px...so all cell devices should be ok.

www.lewisdesigns.com. It works no problem on iPhone. This is why I am stumped why there would be issues for other mobile devices.

```css
.box {
position:absolute;
border: 2px white dotted;
border-radius: 15px;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
left:0;right:0;
width: 380px;
padding: 10px;
}

@media (max-width : 320px) {
.box  { width: 240px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
}

@media (max-width : 425px) {
.box  { width: 240px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
}
 .nav-pills {

  position: relative;
  margin-top:265px;
display:table;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
}
.nav-pills li a {
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 589px;
border-radius:0px;
background-color: white;
display:inline-block;
}
.nav-pills li a:hover {
color: white;
background-color: transparent;
display:inline-block;
border: 1px white solid;
font-weight: 300;
}
@media (max-width : 320px) {
.nav-pills  { width: 280px;
  margin-top: 190px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
}
@media (max-width : 425px) {
.nav-pills  { width: 280px;
  margin-top: 210px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
}

@media (max-width : 320px) {
.nav-pills li a { font-size:12px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin:2px;
}
}
@media (max-width : 425px) {
.nav-pills li a { font-size:12px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin:2px;
}
}




.box h2 {
  
font:  70px/1.2 'Pacifico', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 4px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
margin-left: 15px;
}


 .box span {
  margin-left: 70px;
 }

@media (max-width : 320px) {
.box h2 { font:  50px/1.2 'Pacifico', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
}
@media (max-width : 320px) {
.box span { margin-left: 40px;
}
}

@media (max-width : 425px) {
.box h2 { font:  50px/1.2 'Pacifico', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
}
@media (max-width : 425px) {
.box span { margin-left: 40px;
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div class="header" id="header">
<div class="container">
 <div class="box"> 
 <h2>Lewis <br><span>Designs</span></h2>
 </div>
 <div class="menu">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills"> 
 <li><a href="./about.html">About</a></li> 
 <li><a href="./consultation.html">Consultations</a></li> 
 <li><a href="./gallery.html">Gallery</a></li> 
 <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
  </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure. It's a fairly old phone so I am assuming it would be internet explorer. It wasn't my phone. They were just reporting back to me. Could it be the browser?

Comment: Coule be but IE on an mobile phone is fairy new. That said there's no viewport meta mentioned and your code could use validation.

Comment: I do have viewport meta mentionned.

Comment: Not in the code provided. However, this is probably phone specific so a lot of things may not work.

Comment: No, I know its not in the code provided, but its in my code. I ommited the whole head section from this but maybe I needed to include it. Thanks for your input! :)

Comment: Not sure which browser you're using but I suggest Can I Use:
[http://caniuse.com/#search=media](http://caniuse.com/#search=media)